# Yii CHtml::activeDropDownList

Tags: php, yii

'm brand new to Yii with OOP PHP and I have a project dealing with activeDropDownList.  After research and coding I have the following, but it's not working.

I need to get and show all available sales reps, basically using the same code as getting the CSRs (`PurchasingTrackingController.getCsrs()`), except only using AD path `CN=HitSales,OU=Groups,DC=HIT,DC=local` instead of all three in the `getCsrs()` function, and it'll be named `getSalesReps()`. I've got the drop-down working, but it gets all CSR's and I just need the Sales Reps.

I think the problem is here  Could someone point me in the right direction; what am I missing here?  Thanks in advance!

The model is over 1600 lines of code, but I'll include this, where I think the problem is:

the Controller code:

```
 public function getSalesReps() {
    $ldap = new LDAP();
    $csrs = array();
    $csrs= array_merge($csrs, $ldap->findMembersOf("CN=HitSales,OU=Groups,DC=HIT,DC=local"));
    unset($csrs['']);
    asort($csrs);
    $sreps = array_merge(array('' => ''), $csrs);
    return $sreps;
}


public function getCsrs() {
    $ldap = new LDAP();
    $csrs = array();
    $csrs = array_merge($csrs, $ldap->findMembersOf("CN=HitSales,OU=Groups,DC=HIT,DC=local"));
    $csrs = array_merge($csrs, $ldap->findMembersOf("CN=Customer ServiceGRP,CN=Users,DC=HIT,DC=local"));
    $csrs = array_merge($csrs, $ldap->findMembersOf("CN=Purchasing,CN=Users,DC=HIT,DC=local"));
    unset($csrs['']);
    asort($csrs);
    $csrs = array_merge(array('' => ''), $csrs);
    return $csrs;
}
```

////////////////////////////////
Model: PurchasingTrackingSearchForm

```
public function getCsrs()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->distinct=true;
    $criteria->select="CSR";
    $pos=PurchasingTracking::model()->findAll($criteria);
    $ldap=new LDAP;
    $csrs=array();
    foreach($pos as $po)
    {
        if(($username=$po->CSR)=='')
            continue;
        $result=$ldap->getNameFromUsername($username);
        if(!$result['success'])
            continue;
        $name=$result['name'];
        $csrs[$username]=$name;
    }
    asort($csrs);
    return array('BLANK5'=>'') + $csrs;
}
```

Comment: The View: 
  <tr>
            <th><?php echo CHtml::encode($model->getAttributeLabel('SALES_REP')); ?></td>
            <td class="type-select"><?php echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'SALES_REP', $csrs, array('id' => 'PurchasingTracking_CSR', 'name' => 'PurchasingTracking[CSR]'), array(
                    'type' => 'POST'));
                ?></td>
        </tr>

Comment: in your above code we cant tell how `$csrs` (in your view) was set. also, could you please edit the question to contain your view code? makes reading it a lot easier :)

Comment: @deacs I posted the view as a comment because my question was so ling it wouldn't let me post any more.

Comment: hmm maybe you could try shortening it a little, ie remove `_getCsrsByCriteria()`. although i'd rather see the code that sets `$csrs` now than the view

Comment: @deacs added the $csrs code.